# "please forward us the amount owed" - Is this expression ok for a letter?

Tags: phrases

I am trying to figure out a formal way of asking for a payment. Is the phrase:

> Please forward us the amount owed.

too formal, too outdated or not clear?

Answer (score 2):

The word *forward* might be a little outdated.  What's wrong with *send*?

"Please send us the total amount due by April 25.  Thank you."

Sometimes creditors will add the following:  "If you have already sent us your payment, please disregard this letter!"